# R: How to recode values of a variable to NA for cases where another variable has a value of NA

Tags: r

I'm cleaning a dataset and I need to recode a variable, DebtRatio, to have the value NA when MonthlyIncome has a value of NA. By default this is not true and thus the values which have NA are giving crazy values for DebtRatio (naturally). However these cases have a variety of other interesting information so I dont wish to remove them completely. Simply recode the values of these cases to NA.

However when I run my script, it doesnt seem to behave the way I want. I dont receive an error in the terminal but the values dont change at all.

```
credit_train_18$DebtRatio[credit_train_18$MonthlyIncome == NA] <- NA
```

This works when recoding my categorical variables so I'm not sure why it fails in this particular case.

I would really appreciate a solution to this problem

Comment: Please show a reproducible example.  Also for `NA` values, you need to use `is.na(credit_train_18$MonthlyIncome)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use is.na() rather than checking for equality.

```
credit_train_18$DebtRatio[is.na(credit_train_18$MonthlyIncome)] <- NA
```

Your approach is problematic because NA == NA returns NA rather than TRUE.

Comment: Yes this is a perfect solution. I see where my issue was coming from now. I'll have to be much more careful in the future. I just wasted a couple of days fruitlessly googling such a simple problem.